# convert string arrays to integer then get the sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array from a database output and I would like to convert them to integers then get the sum. 'How' can I change them to integers and add all numbers on each array just like the one below (array1)?

```
 array = ['[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]', '[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]', '[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]', '[3, 43, 3, 3, 
           5]','[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]', '[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]'] 


 array1 = [57,57,57,57,57,57]
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` to convert the strings to arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result first parsing

```
"[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]"
```

to

```
[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]
```

using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add the array elements

```js
const array = [
  "[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]",
  "[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]",
  "[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]",
  "[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]",
  "[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]",
  "[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]",
];

const result = array.map((a) => JSON.parse(a).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr));

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON.parse` function for this

```js
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// this will do `JSON.parse('[3, 43, 3, 3, 5]')` to get an array with the actual values
let arrayWithParsedArrays = array.map(i => JSON.parse(i))

// this will use reducer to sun each array
let array1 = arrayWithParsedArrays.map(i => i.reduce(reducer))
```